# Is "мде"/"мдя" a gender-specific word?

Tags: словоупотребление, междометие

It seems that in Internet discussions only women use this interjection.

Is it gender-specific?

It seems that the word "секес"/"секас" is also gender-specific.

What are other gender-specific words in Russian?

Comment: please, provide some examples, not sure your assumption is correct.

Comment: @shabunc http://www.baby.ru/blogs/post/58753207-45658355/ http://helena-lawliet.livejournal.com/1073.html

Comment: Просто каждый пишет как слышит или как привык. Или Вы думаете, что, например, женщины смеются "ха-ха-ха", а мужчины - "а-ха-хах"?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but it seems to me that the word "секас" is one case of the modern trend to write the word as you hear it. Therefore, this is not a legal word at all. Just as one can write in chat "пасиба" or "щас" which will be of course understood by native speakers but itself isn't a separate word.

Comment: @petajamaja I never hear "секас" in real life.

Comment: "секас" maybe related to the cacographic trends in internet slang, but it seems to me it was popularized by "Наша Russia" sitcom. Also I'm not sure what does "gender-specific" mean in that context. Can you provide some examples of gender-specific words?

Answer (score 4):

These are not gender-specific words. This is a distortion of normal words used by immature personalities.

Often these distortions are used to mask obscene or indecent words.

I think that "м-да", "м-де", "м-дя" could be translated as "eh", because they express disappointment. It may also be that women often use "мдя" because it sounds similar to the Japanese "nya"...

"Секес", "Секас" refers to sex and the correct spelling is "секс".

To answer your second question, in the Russian language there are no gender-specific words and expressions as far as I can remember.

Comment: what about "чмоке"? )))

Comment: @shabunc чмоке = XOXO

Comment: @shabunc do you mean чмоки?

Comment: @Anixx - да, в интернетах кое-где встречается тенденция намеренной замены окончания -и в мн.ч. на -е, наиболее часто - в словах  "сиське", "попке". Фсем чмоке в этом чяти.

Comment: "чмоке" = kiss. E.g.: "всем чмоке в этом чате!" = "Kiss all in this chat!"